# UIView with animation using swift 3

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3

my problem is that i want a Gauge with animation, but the animation doesn't work, the gauge only go to my value without animation, i'm new in swift 3 so i don't know what's my mistake and all my research doesn't match with my problem

I think the problem is with the refresh of my view but i don't know to do

Here is my ViewControler :

**DashboardViewController**

```
    class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var counterPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var counterView: CounterView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let consumptionPrice: Double = Double(counterView.counter) * price / 1000
    counterLabel.text = String(counterView.counter) + "W"
    counterPrice.text = String(consumptionPrice) + "€*/heure"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func ChangeCounter(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let randomNum:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(100)
    let counterRandom = Int(randomNum) * 60

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.3, animations: {
        self.counterView.counter = counterRandom

    }, completion: nil)

    counterLabel.text = String(counterView.counter) + "W"
}
```

}

And here my UIView with my gauge :

**CounterView**

```
@IBDesignable class CounterView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var counter: Int = 3000 {
    didSet {
        //the view needs to be refreshed
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var outlineColor: UIColor = UIColor.orange
@IBInspectable var counterColor: UIColor = UIColor.cyan

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 7
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 5 * π / 6
    let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 6


    let angleDifference: CGFloat = 2 * π - startAngle + endAngle

    let arcLengthConsumption = angleDifference / CGFloat(mMaxPowerSubscribed)

    let outlineEndAngle = arcLengthConsumption * CGFloat(counter) + startAngle

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                   radius: radius/2.5 - arcWidth/2,
                                   startAngle: startAngle,
                                   endAngle: outlineEndAngle,
                                   clockwise: true)

    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

}

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try this method in Swift3.0 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {...code......}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
  ..code..
})      Please also check whether 'counterRandom' has a new value

Comment: I try your method but the result is the same i don't see any animation even if i put 3 sec for duration